# Get Json of a Restful service

Tags: web-services, jersey

I have a Restful service with Jersey where I return Json data, the problem is when I try to get the data with $.ajax I'm not able get it.
My Restful service is:

```
@Path("/RegistroJson")
public class RegistroJson {

@GET
@Path("/get/{param}/{param2}/{param3}")

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Usuario htmlHello(@PathParam("param") String nick,@PathParam("param2") String pass,@PathParam("param3") String email) {
    Usuario u=new Usuario();
    u.setPass(pass);
    u.setUser(nick);
    u.setEmail(email);
    return u;
}
```

I need the json in the web but I'm not able to get it with this:

```
$.ajax({url: "http://localhost:8080/RestWebService/rest/RegistroJson/get/emilio/adf/asdf"})
```

I use that command with this service(http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting) and it works correctly so I think the problem is in my rest service
Could you help me with this? 
Thank you

Comment: Where are you performing the rest Web-request? In a browser or in Jersey?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to this rest url with browser, do you receive json data? In $.json() you need to add an success action when your received data will be accessible. You can do this by adding to {} option `success:function(f){ console.log(f) }`

Comment: Yes, if I go to the rest url I receive the json data

Comment: Try to add what i have written. Your json should look like: $.ajax({         url: "http://localhost:8080/RestWebService/rest/RegistroJson/get/emilio/adf/asdf", success:function(f){console.log(f); } then check your console in browser do you see your data.